# Can we add button inside contact picker intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts, contactpicker

I want to use the contact picker intent in my app. I also want to have functionality of adding a contact from the same intent. I searched for if we can combine the contact picker intent and the insert intent but it seems not possible. So Can we add a button inside the contact picker intent. How can we do it? Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

No. The `ACTION_PICK` activity is a UI provided by another app. You cannot modify it. You can implement your own contact picker UI, by querying `ContactsContract` for available contacts and showing them directly.